# How to parse two different types in one parser in Scala?

Tags: scala, parsing, rdd, type-mismatch

I have written the following part of code to parse RDD type and Float in an expression.  To parse an arithmetic expression consisting float and RDD like: "firstRDD + 2" :

```
def term2: Parser[List[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]]] = rep(factor2)
def factor2: Parser[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = pathxml | num  
def pathxml: Parser[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]] = pathIdent ^^ {s => pathToRDD(s) } //pathToRDD is a function that gets the path in string and create an RDD from the file inside that path and pathIdent parse to see whether the input string is a path or not
def num: Parser[Float] = floatingPointNumber ^^ (_.toFloat)
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
  [error] type mismatch;
  [error]  found   : ParseExp.this.Parser[Float]
  [error]  required: ParseExp.this.Parser[Either[Float,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]]]
  [error]   def factor2: Parser[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = pathxml | num 
  [error]                                                                           ^
```

I don't know how to do that except using "Either" and don't know how to solve this type mismatch!
Note that if I use "Any" it is not able to parse the RDD.

Comment: What's the `Parser` class you use there? I can't find the corresponding API docs.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a union type as defined in http://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/.  There is a simple working example at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zalacer/projects-tn/master/UnionTypeDemo/src/tn/UnionTypeDemo.scala.

Comment: @TrisNefzger that's the proper way to do it, I agree. But Rubbic doesn't seem to be too familiar with the beautiful sides of scala, so I didn't want to overdo it.

Comment: Yeah I am new in Scala and being a beginner writing a huge program is like a pain! Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wants an `Either` instead of a `Float`, so you give it an `Either`.
But we cannot simply create the value from the output, because the
Parser works with functions, not values.

```
def num: Parser[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = floatingPointNumber ^^ (n => Left(n).toFloat)
```

and hope it works. If it doesn't, go the long route:

```
def num: Parser[Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = floatingPointNumber ^^ (n =>
  val res: Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]] = n.toFloat
  res
)
```

Or the scalaz route (you'll have to rewrite the code to use `\/`
instead of `Either`:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def term2: Parser[List[\/[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]]] = rep(factor2)
def factor2: Parser[\/[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = pathxml | num
def pathxml: Parser[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]] = pathIdent ^^ {s => pathToRDD(s) } //pathToRDD is a function that gets the path in string and create an RDD from the file inside that path and pathIdent parse to see whether the input string is a path or not
def num: Parser[\/[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = floatingPointNumber ^^ (n => n.left[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]].toFloat)
```

`left` and `right` from scalaz do pretty much what you would expect -
they create a left or a right value. The type argument you pass to
left or right is used to construct the full type, because the value
only provides the left or right type, but the full either type needs
the type of the other side (right/left) as well, so the other type
needs to be passed as well.

On another hand, I think you'll get a similar error message later with
pathxml. Fix it in a similar manner, except with `Right` instead of `Left`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using Scala combinator parser. what does ".left[..]" do here? because the type of num would be a Float, and pathexml would be the RDD one.

Comment: `.left` is from `scalaz`, which I've used recently so that's what I used by instinct. The `Either` from the stdlib is a bit more messy. I reordered the code snippets.

Comment: Got it, Is there any specific import needed at the beginning ? I am getting an error for ".left" says:  value left is not a member of ParseExp.this.Parser[Float]

Comment: Try if the second snippet works (reload the page, I reodered stuff).

Comment: I tried and it is giving the following errors: 
 type mismatch;
[error]  found   : ParseExp.this.Parser[Float]
[error] required: Float
[error] val numeither: Either[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]] = Left(num)
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Either[Float,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]]
[error]  required: ParseExp.this.Parser[Either[Float,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]]]
[error] pathxml | numeither
[error]                ^

Comment: Also is there anything else I need to do for Scalaz ? I put the import in the code and got the following error: not found: value scalaz

Comment: See https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz - but it won't work either, because the parser api requires functions, not values. Lemme think.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I used the last update of yours and now this is the new error: 
[error] type mismatch;  
[error]  found   : ParseExp.this.Parser[Serializable]  
[error]  required:   ParseExp.this.Parser[scalaz.\/[Float,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]]]
[error]   def factor2: Parser[\/[Float, RDD[(Int,Array[Float])]]] = pathxml | num

Comment: would you please guide me, since I am using my own "pathToRDD" function to change String into the RDD how can I fit your solution (writing the "right") for that?

Comment: `Serializable` means it can't find a lower upper bound for type unification. It usually helps to assign intermediate values to `val x: TypeSpelledOut = res1` and ask the compiler where exactly your thoughts differ from what the compiler sees.

Comment: I have assigned intermediate value like: "val num2: Float =num" and I'm getting error of num is scalaz.\/[Float , RDD] type found Float! , am I on the right track?

Comment: I think you should get a `Parser[Float]` at least. You aren't operating on values, you're operating on functions. But otherwise, it sounds good.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me, I did that actually and I got the error of founding  "ParseExp.this.Parser[scalaz.\/[Float,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]]]" required :" ParseExp.this.Parser[Float]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83086/discussion-between-reactormonk-and-rubbic).